# What is the JDBC Driver Name for Oracle database on Corda?

Tags: oracle, corda

What is the value of the `jdbcSession` that needs to be sent to `serviceHub` when working with an Oracle database?

https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.node/-service-hub/jdbc-session.html

Answer (score 0):

The value is a plain string without version number:
`const val JDBC_DRIVER_NAME = "Oracle JDBC driver"`

For a reference of which Oracle database are supported by Corda see: https://docs.corda.r3.com/platform-support-matrix.html#databases